# Does FormApp have a method to send the Form using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

After having built a form for a survey I wanted to develope a script to send the form to each email address contained in a Google Spreadsheet.

On the Form App builder there is a big blue button "Send" which can send the form to an email address.  Looking at FormApp there are no methods to send the form.

Is there a way from the Form App script editor to do this?  I want to connect the Spreadsheet to the Form App script to cycle through the list of email addresses in one column and send a form to each email address.

Comment: As a work around, have you tried getting the published form url using [getPublishedUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getpublishedurl)? What I had in mind is that you can just send the users on your email list with the url generated with `getPublishedUrl()` instead.

Comment: @PatrickdC I think TheWizEd wants the embed feature in the send button, where the form is embedded directly in the email. @ TheWizEd  No, probably not.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @TheMaster. I also think that there is no feature for this method yet. This is why I presented an alternative. However, you may also file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=978479&template=1644354) for this.

Comment: I know an alternative is to use GMailApp from the Spreadsheet and just develope a petty html email content with a link as a button, but I was hoping I could do everything from FormApp.  Thanks.